# Swift won't allow me to use `!=`

Tags: ios, swift, if-statement, null

Currently trying to check if three values, that I just converted from Strings to doubles, are `nil` from the UITextFields `aValue`, `bValue`, and `cValue`.

I don't get a compile error from these variables until  the if statement at the bottom of the code block (shown below) where it causes a compile error that says `Cannot invoke '!-' with an argument list of type '($T10, $T14)'`.

```
    var a = (aValue.text as NSString).doubleValue
    var b = (bValue.text as NSString).doubleValue
    var c = (cValue.text as NSString).doubleValue
    if a != nil && b != nil && c != nil
```

Can anyone help me fix this error? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Just compare to `0`. `Double`s are not objects but **basic data types**, which don't allow `nil`. Instead of `a != nil`, use `a != 0` or something equivalent.

Comment: @AlejandroIván Please don't post answers as comments.

Comment: @nhgrif it wasn't meant as an answer, but as a comment. I was expecting something else to give him a full answer with an example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

doubleValue can not be nil. A double value of NSString is a simple type (double) and can not have nil as value, so the compiler can not compare them. You can check if your NSString is nil or if the doubleValue is 0.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer the much more compact let chain version:

```
if let a = Double(aValue.text!),
   let b = Double(bValue.text!),
   let c = Double(cValue.text!) {
    println(true)
}
```